# How to add new div to wordpress admin login panel

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to somehow insert a new div into the admin login panel.

functions.php

```
<?php
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

wp_enqueue_style( 'amereo-login-styles', get_theme_file_uri('login-styles.css'), [], false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'amereo-login-scripts', get_theme_file_uri('login-scripts.js'), [], false, true);
} );
```

login-styles.css

```
    #login a {
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("images/login_logo.png");
    }
    
    body.login
    {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size:cover;
    background-image: url("images/1.png");
    cursor: url('images/cursor.png'), default;
    }
```

login-scripts.js
`//empty`

(Most probably I could edit the wp-login.php file only I would like to get this effect using my theme)
Is this even possible?

Comment: You can make use of [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) in your JS file. You need to use [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) with the parent element where you want to insert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [login_init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_init/) hook for this.

```
add_action('login_init', function(){
    ?>
        <div>
            Your custom div
        </div>
    <?php

});
```